# No action happens when form button pressed

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that contains two button 
but when I press on one of them nothing happen
and I can't find the problem can you help me please !!

here my `php` code :

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    include 'connection.php';

    // in this section, I retrieve data from database and display them on table 
    // if agree button pressed do the following

 if (isset($_POST['agree']))
    {
$que="update project set status='submitted' ,projectstatus=1 where projectid=$id ";
$result3=mysql_query($que);
        if ($result3)
        {

            echo(" <script>
            alert('The project has been approved');
            </script>");

             header( "Location:unsubmited.php" );

        }
        else
        {
            echo "an error occur can't agree on this project";
        }


    }
    ?>
```

and this is the form :

```
<form action='' method='post'>
   <input type='button' name='disagree' value='disagree ' class='styled-button-11'>
   <input type='button' name='agree' value='agree' class='styled-button-11'>
   </form>
```

thanx ^^

Comment: You need to make the inputs `type='submit'`. At the moment, your browser doesn't know that the form is supposed to be submitted when you press the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code for this, as it says andrewsi:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='disagree' value='disagree ' class='styled-button-11'>
<input type='submit' name='agree' value='agree' class='styled-button-11'>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you this was the problem ... can I ask you another question about this code?

Comment: when the update happens it should show the alert then redirect to another page but the alert didn't show it  went to unsubmited.php directly why?

Comment: What you could do is add a validation in php, run when it detects "click" the button was make it to be processed, and if the execution is successful, display a success message and redirect to page you want, otherwise an error message

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is as simple as, filling in the `action=''` to the page to post back to and setting the `type='submit'` as andrewsi suggested.

Comment: no the action should be in the same page so it's not necessary to fill it ,the problem was type='submit' not button like what andrewsi said to me ..... thanx

Comment: my answer covered that as andresi posted while I was writing as well. His comment came through before I finished, however and so I attribute it to him since the comment is also right. That said, leaving action blank is generally poor practice because you're not assured that the browser will default to it's source.

Comment: so what is your suggestion to make it not poor ?

Comment: Simply fill in the `action='<pageName>.php'`. You could get more fancy that that but it's really unnecessary.